# How can I get a positional argument to handle a terminal wildcard?

Tags: python, list, wildcard

I am to write a short piece of code as  positional argument that is a list of files at the end of a style argument that can handle terminal wilcards like */.txt.

I've already been able to write the code to reflect the question, but I'm thrown by the wildcard as I don't know what it means.

This is the code that I have at the moment:

```
animals = ['bear', 'fox', 'deer', 'eagle', 'd;lphin']
print(animals)
```

The impression I have is that the wildcard will correct d?lphin but I'm not sure. Running this code will show the list, but how can I introduce the wildcard on the next lines and what should the code look like.

Comment: `'d;lphin'` - is that a typo?

Comment: No, an online forum suggested that a wildcard would correct a typo.

Comment: I was going to say you want `glob.glob`, but now I'm not sure. Please [edit] to add your expected output.

Comment: It's possible I am writing in the wrong place, but put simply, what is a wildcard.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character

Comment: `d?lphin` is a wildcard, `d;lphin` is not.

Comment: That's interesting, so a wildcard has a ? included?